# Запросы к БД на выборку данных

Tags: mysql

Это файл подключения к БД `connect.php`

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'chat', 'pass', 'chat');
    if (!$connect) {
        die('Error connect to DataBase');
    }
```

В базе находится таблица users, в которой есть столбцы `id`, `full_name`, `login`, `email`, `password`, `avatar`, `reg_date`.
Как написать запрос, позволяющий вывести на экран конкретный столбец с данными?
Я уже пробовал разные комбинации этих строчек:

```
            $sql = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT `reg_date` FROM `users` WHERE `id` > 30");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
            echo $row;
```

Но никак не получается, пишет просто "Array". Как мне решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо

Comment: `echo $row['reg_date'];` И да - почитай мануал https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

Comment: Неа, все равно не работает. Можете набросать код страницы, где есть все для запроса? Может я логику где-то не так прописал

Comment: Никто за вас писать не будет. Вам дали ссылку на документацию, так воспользуйтесь ею. Попробуйте выполнить **var_dump($row);** чтобы увидеть структуру массива.

Comment: @3xcepts да и там будет судя по всему 0-indexed массив)

Comment: Получилось вывести только 1 запись из этого столбца. А что бы вывести весь столбец, как нужно написать запрос? Я вроде прямиком из mysql запрос копировал, там все работает, а на сайте выводится только 1 запись...

Comment: Чтобы вернуть все результаты, нужно повторять `mysqli_fetch_array($sql);` до тех пор, пока функция возвращает результат. Или воспользоваться функцией https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php